# Expression is not accepted in table element when switching between Source and WYSISYG in CKEditor 4.7

Tags: html, ckeditor, spring-el, ckeditor4.x

I am making a report template that is required for my school project. Inside the report, I need to display all the cars and their respective details. As you can see from the code below, I am using spring expression language to perform loop on return data and it works as intended.

```
<div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        $foreach{car: entity.cars}
        <tr>
            <td>${car.name}</td>
            <td>${car.color}</td>
            <td>${car.model}</td>
        </tr>
        $end{}
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

However, **when I switch between Source and WYSISYG, the whole expression will be omitted from the table element** and become like this:

```
<div> $foreach{car: entity.cars}   $end{}
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>${car.name}</td>
            <td>${car.color}</td>
            <td>${car.model}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I have read the documentation from CKEditor and found out there's a feature called 'ACF'. It helps us to discards invalid, useless HTML tags and attributes so the editor remains "clean" during runtime.

I already tried

```
 config.allowedContent = true;
```

I am not particularly sure whether my problem is caused by the 'ACF' feature. If it does, how can I configure it so that the editor will ignore the expression and leave it as it is?

## EDIT

I tested the code above with another rich text editor (RTE) out there. Unfortunately, it turns out all of them return the same result. I believe it is illegal to put such an expression between the table elements in an RTE. How should I modify my code so that it is syntactically correct in an RTE?

Answer (score 0):

I just got a workaround for this issue. I noticed the editor will not remove SPEL if I specifically tell it not to do so in the 'config.js' file.

You can achieve this by configuring protectedSource. For more details, please check this link:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-protectedSource